# Attempting to align all input boxes in the center of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently I am making a form that has multiple inputs and I am using flex box to make these inputs appear in a column, and text-align center to get the whole form into a centered row. I am attempting to get the text boxes all be in the center of the page and the text move over accordingly.

```css
.mainForm {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.radio {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

textarea {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  resize: none;
}

.feedBack {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="information">

  <p class="formInputs"> Policy Number:
    <input id="polNum" name="polNum" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayPolicyNumber()" /></p>
  <p class="print">Policy Number: <span class="display" id="display_policyNumber"></span></p>

  <p class="formInputs">Control Number:
    <input id="membNbr" name="membNbr" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayControlNumber()" /></p>
  <p class="print">Control Number: <span class="display" id="display_controlNumber"></span></p>

  <p class="formInputs">Last Name or Business Name:
    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayLastName()" /></p>
  <p class="print">Last Name or Business Name: <span class="display" id="display_lastName"></span></p>

  <p class="formInputs">First Name :
    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayFirstName()" /></p>
  <p class="print">First Name: <span class="display" id="display_firstName"></span></p>

  <p class="formInputs">Comments:
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="2" onkeyup="javascript:displayComments()"></textarea></p>
  <p class="print">Comments: <span class="display" id="display_comment"></span></p>

</div>
```

Comment: add your css also

Comment: This is a tricky question, because we do not actually know the exact outcome you want. For example, if the text is very long such that it breaks across multiple lines, how are you planning to align it? Do you want the fields to be centered? Do you have a fixed (or min/max) width for the associated input labels?

Comment: these fields will be used by agents that will use minimum amounts  of text less than 10-12 characters. I want the input boxes to be center to the page and the text to left no matter how long pushed to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your input/textarea to be absolutely centered, you will have to wrap your text in the `<label>` element (or any other HTML element, but for usability reason you should always use `<label>`). That is because we want to position the text independently of the input. An example:

```
<p class="formInputs">
  <label for="polNum">Policy Number:</label>
  <input id="polNum" name="polNum" type="text" />
</p>
```

When that is done, you can use the following trick:

1. Set a fixed width for your input elements. Let's say we want them to be `200px` wide. Instead of setting this on the input elements themselves, we set it on the containing parent, `.formInputs`, and then set input elements to take up this full width.
2. Position the `<label>` element absolutely within the `.formInputs` parent. Set it to `right: 100%` so that it will be offset to the left by the full width of the parent.
3. Use a right padding so that the right edge of the label text is not directly sticking to the left border of your input

See proof-of-concept below:

```css
textarea {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  resize: none;
}

.formInputs {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.formInputs label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.formInputs input,
.formInputs textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="information">

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="polNum">Policy Number:</label>
    <input id="polNum" name="polNum" type="text" />
  </p>

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="membNbr">Control Number:</label>
    <input id="membNbr" name="membNbr" type="text" />
  </p>

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name or Business Name:</label>
    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" />
  </p>

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" />
  </p>

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="comment">Comments:</label>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
.information{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcgfqjh9/

Comment: Yes it looks like this however I would like for the inputs to be aligned together instead of everything being centered on the page

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your form in a div.
2. Set the div's display to block and text-align to center (this will
   center the contained form).
3. Set the form's display to inline-block (auto-sizes to content), left
   and right margins to auto (centers it horizontally), and
   text-align to left (or else its children will be center-aligned too).

HTML file

```
<div class="form">
    <form method = "post", action=""> 
        --------- 
    </form>
</div>
```

in .css 
use like this

```
 div.form { 
        display: inline-block; 
        text-align: center; 
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `center` tag - it has been deprecated in favour of CSS `text-align`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML 5 and should not be used, as it won't always be supported by future browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">` use this one

Comment: Hmmm, but why? There is no indication that the OP is using a framework like bootstrap.

Comment: `form {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}`   use this one

Comment: Improve your existing answer, Kumar, and explain why your suggestion is helpful and how it effectively addresses the issue. The comment section is not intended for alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the whole thing in a wrapper, apply flex with the below settings to it to center the form, and apply flex and `justify-content: space-between` to the single lines (i.e. the `.formInputs` elements) to align the text and input fields at the left and right border:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.formInputs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="information">

    <p class="formInputs"> Policy Number:
      <input id="polNum" name="polNum" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayPolicyNumber()" /></p>
    <p class="print">Policy Number: <span class="display" id="display_policyNumber"></span></p>

    <p class="formInputs">Control Number:
      <input id="membNbr" name="membNbr" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayControlNumber()" /></p>
    <p class="print">Control Number: <span class="display" id="display_controlNumber"></span></p>

    <p class="formInputs">Last Name or Business Name:
      <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayLastName()" /></p>
    <p class="print">Last Name or Business Name: <span class="display" id="display_lastName"></span></p>

    <p class="formInputs">First Name :
      <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:displayFirstName()" /></p>
    <p class="print">First Name: <span class="display" id="display_firstName"></span></p>

    <p class="formInputs">Comments:
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="2" onkeyup="javascript:displayComments()"></textarea></p>
    <p class="print">Comments: <span class="display" id="display_comment"></span></p>

  </div>
</div>
```